# Error message - java:24: Incompatible types

Tags: java, compiler-errors, concatenation

I keep getting this error message every time I try to compile my program:

```
SeasonTest.java:24: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: int
        int date = ("" + mo + day);
                           ^
1 error
```

I'm trying to concatenate two integers to form another integer variable within a string return method:

```
static String season (int month, int day)
{
    int date = ("" + month + day);

    String season;

    if (date >= 316 && date <= 615)
    {
        season = "spring";
        return season;
    }
```

I've played around with it and I can't understand what the problem is at all.

Answer (score 1):

`int date = ("" + month + day);`

`date` is of *type* `int`, when you do `"" + month + day;` the result will be a String. You can't assign a String to an `int` - As the compiler error clearly says.

This is like writing:

```
int date = new StringBuilder("").append(month).append(day).toString();
```

Which results in compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

This initial code

```
int date = ("" + month + day); // Yields a string.
```

Should probably be something along these lines.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // get a calendar instance.
int date = day;
for (int i = 0; i < month; i++) {
  c.set(Calendar.MONTH, i); // set the month.
  date += c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); //how many days are in that month?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) has a few things to say about this:

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.
>
> The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand operand in the newly created string.
>
> The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a compile-time constant expression (§15.28).

In layman's terms:

- Any `String` instance or literal found next to the overloaded `+` operator turns the entire right-hand expression into a `String`.
- The concatenation will succeed unless the result of the concatenation will produce a compile-time error.  In this case, it's attempting to assign a `String` to an `int` - which is an obvious non-starter.

My advice would be to simply remove the empty string from your expression.

As to the correctness of your actual program:  I leave it as an exercise to you, but if you're merely determining seasons, then look at three-month blocks of time.  In the northern hemisphere, December 20th (ish) through March 20th (ish) is considered Winter.  Use this as a rough guide to determine your logic.

Answer (score 0):

When you append anything to a string then the expression result is an string. So the following statement will result in a string value:

```
("" + month + day)
```

and you are trying to assign this to an int value, leading to an error. You may have to do this:

```
int date = Integer.valueOf("" + month + day);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding "" to two integers, which becomes a String. You then cannot assign that String to an int.

Here are two possible solutions:

```
int date = month + day;

int date = Integer.parseInt("" + month + day); // same as below solution
```

I think what you are trying to do however is concatenate the day to the month:

```
int date = (100 * month) + day;
```

Comment: month + day will give different result because this is addition not concatenation. I beleive the user wants to concatenate the two values instead of adding them.

Comment: @JunedAhsan, yes I think that is what my 3rd line of code does?

Answer (score 0):

Others gave correct answers. But let me add:

- A caveat: The start of spring varies by definition, locale, and year. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_%28season%29).
- Some example code using Joda-Time which supplants the notoriously bad java.util.Date/Calendar classes bundled with Java.

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 in Java 7, some example code.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

int year = 2013; // Arbitrarily chosen year.

// Using day before, and day after, Spring to make the if() statement below simpler (no need to check OR EQUALS).
LocalDate springPre = new LocalDate( year, DateTimeConstants.MARCH, 16 ).minusDays( 1 );
LocalDate springPost = new LocalDate( year, DateTimeConstants.JUNE, 15 ).plusDays( 1 );

int month = 4; // Pair of arguments passed to your method.
int day = 22;

LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( year, month, day );

Boolean isSpring;
if ( ( localDate.isAfter( springPre ) ) && ( localDate.isBefore( springPost ) ) ) {
    isSpring = true;
} else {
    isSpring = false;
}

System.out.println( "The date: " + localDate + " is in Spring: " + isSpring );
```

When run…

```
The date: 2013-04-22 is in Spring: true
```